# Unable to dispatch an action after updating the route using router.push

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

When trying to dispatch an action after updating the route using `this.$router`, the action uses the previous route parameters instead of using the current route parameters.

Suppose I want to move to the `/home` and currently, I am on `/about` and in the store action `called` I want to access the route name, but after pushing the new route and then calling the action, it is using the previous route only and not the updated one.

```
this.$router.push('/home', this.$store.dispatch('called'))
```

Also, I tried using `this.$router.push('/home').then(this.$store.dispatch('called'))`, but it gives undefined error.

Comment: What does this action do?  There may be a better place to call it, depending.

Comment: @Dan, it just fetches any query from the route, if present.

Comment: In that case, try to call it from the `beforeEnter` or `beforeEach` [route guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard).

Comment: But, I only want to check for whether a query is present or not when clicking a specific method and that method call is also responsible for changing the route.

Comment: Why not pass the query to the action?

Comment: Yes, I can do that but the issue is that the action is taking the previous route into consideration when checking the query, if I will pass something like `this.$route.query` then it is checking for the query of the previous route and not the current one.

Comment: Right, you need to pass the *new* query to the action from whatever method pushes the new route.  Then the action can compare the new to the old if it requires both.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the old and new queries from the method:

```
methods: {
  changeRoute() {
    const queryNew = { id: 1 };                              // Create new query
    const queryOld = { ...this.$route.query };               // Clone old query
    this.$router.push({ path: '/home', query: queryNew });   // Navigate
    this.$store.dispatch('called', { queryNew, queryOld });  // Call the action
  }
}
```

The action signature should look like:

```js
actions: {
  called({ commit }, { queryNew, queryOld }) {
    console.log(queryNew, queryOld);
  }
}
```